Where did $1/2$ of this come from?

Work done by an external force $F$ upon a particle displacing from point 1 to point 2 is defined as
$$
W_{12} = \int_1^2 F \cdot dr
\, .$$
Kinetic energy and work-energy theorem: According to Newton's second law, $F = m dv/dt$ and hence
\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}
& = m \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} \cdot d\mathbf{r}
= m \frac{d\mathbf{v}}{dt} \cdot \mathbf{v}dt \\
(\text{this line}) \qquad & = m \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{v} \right] dt \\
& = d \left[ \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \right]
\end{align}

This is a lesson on work-energy theorem in classical mechanics.

This question is similar to: Why there is a 1/2 in kinetic energy formula?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Do you understand how to differentiate the scalar (dot) product of two vectors?

It's vector calculus. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/159284/

If:
$$ f(v) = \tfrac12v^2$$
then:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{df(v)}{dt} &= \frac{df(v)}{dv} \frac{dv}{dt} \\
                 &= \frac{2v}{2} \frac{dv}{dt} \\
                 &= v \frac{dv}{dt}
\end{align}$$
$$ \therefore v \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d(\tfrac12v^2)}{dt}$$
It’s just calculus. It’s a neat trick that we use in vector calculus for some derivations.

Please use MathJax.

Hi Anirudh. I've converted your image to MathJax. Have a quick read through and make sure you are happy with the changes I've made.

This is the 1D case, not the 3D case.
